# Cannot import name 'ResNet50_Weights' from 'torchvision.models.resnet'

Tags: pytorch, torchvision

I was previously loading a ResNet model with the ResNet50_Weights parameter successfully, but then suddenly I started getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "splitting_models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from torchvision.models.resnet import ResNet50_Weights
ImportError: cannot import name 'ResNet50_Weights' from 'torchvision.models.resnet' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/models/resnet.py)
```

Here is the import:

```
from torchvision.models import ResNet50_Weights
```

How could I go about fixing this?

PyTorch version: 1.2.0

TorchVision version: 0.4.0

### EDIT

Upgrading using

```
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```

to the following versions fixed the issue:

PyTorch version: 1.12.0

TorchVision version: 0.13.0

Comment: Specify which version of torchvision and pytorch you are using? Try if upgrading/downgrading torchvision to a different version fixes the issue.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The problem took me some days to solve it.
Before running a code containing the Pytorch models, make sure you are connected to a stable network. This because for the first time when you are running a Pytorch model such resnet50, alexnet, resnet18 it downloads its' functionalities, so incase of installation error it caches its downloads and draws such error, if you try to re-run. To solve the problem locate where the cache file is, do delete it and try to re-run the code having a stable network.
for my case:

```
C:\Users\user/.cache\torch\hub\checkpoints\resnet18-f37072fd.pth
```

this where the is cached file was, delete it and try to re-run having a stable network.

I hope it will help.
Thanks regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can try upgrading/downgrading torchvision to a different version. It may fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by getting the cuda version.
Already answered but just upgrading wasnt enough for me.

When checking the version

```
import torchvision
torchvision.__version__
```

I would get

`'0.17.0+cpu'`

Then uninstalled and installed it again and it installed the right version and was able to import ResNet18_Weights

`pip3 uninstall torchvision`

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu121`

New version:

`'0.17.0+cu121'`

`from torchvision.models import resnet18, ResNet18_Weights`

`Downloading: "https://download.pytorch.org/models/resnet18-f37072fd.pth" to C:\Users\USER/.cache\torch\hub\checkpoints\resnet18-f37072fd.pth 100.0%`